# How does Java decide when to import?

Tags: java, class, import

Why doesn't Java need to import classes like Integer, String, etc. while it needs to import other classes?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is an implicit import of `java.lang.*`.

From the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html):

> A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.

Comment: Is `java.lang` the only one auto-import package?

Comment: java.lang is a package containing basic classes essential to the language, while java.lang.* is group of several packages, each containing classes which do not appear in java.lang.  They're completely different things.  And java.lang is the only auto-imported package.

Answer (score 35):

`java.lang` package is imported by default, no need to explicitly import it.

Answer (score 9):

Classes in the [`java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) package do not need to be imported (the compiler acts like they are always imported). This package includes core classes such as String, Enum, Runnable, NullPointerException, and of course, the primitive wrapper classes such as Integer and Double.

Comment: java.lang is imported automatically, you do not need to import it manually.

Comment: @sjas Is that any different from what I have stated in my answer?

Comment: 'The compiler acts like they are always imported.' ... javac does not act like if they are, they are imported. I do not want to split hairs, you just did not explain things correctly. BTW: I upvoted your post for mentioning some examples being contained in java.lang. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Because, they belongs to `java.lang.*` package. And, it is implicitly import by the compiler. If you do, then it won't complain you.

Answer (score 3):

[java.lang](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) is in-build, implicitly imported in java, does'nt need to be manually imported

Answer (score 1):

As it contains very frequently used classes, they have made it optional to import just for your convenience

Answer (score 1):

every class in java is in  a package and if no package is defined then it is understood as in default package. And at the top of the package is java.lang.* so we don't need to import it an require to import other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Integer,String etc classes are present in package java.lang which is default imported.

Answer (score 0):

For the question for
"Is java.lang the only one auto-import package?" There is two packages.

1. java.lang
2. unnamed

you can look up here for more.
https://www.quora.com/Which-package-is-available-by-default-in-java

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.