# Why don't I have to import some classes?

Tags: java, import

Look at this `.java` file:

```
class A {
    HashMap a;
}
```

It doesn't compile; I need to `import java.util.HashMap;`. Now consider this one:

```
class A {
    String a;
}
```

It's exactly the same—except with `String` instead of `HashMap`—so it shouldn't compile, right? Wrong.

Okay, so it's pretty well-known that you don't have to import `String`, but *why* is that? The "obvious" answer is because `String` is used far more often than `HashMap`, but then shouldn't `ArrayList` be "implicitly imported"? What about the the primitive wrapper classes, e.g. `Integer` and `Boolean`? `ArrayList` is used *far* more often than `Long` and `Float`, but I have to import `ArrayList` and don't need to import `Float`.

What is the reason behind not needing to import `String`, `Integer`, `Character`, `Exception` and a few other classes?

Comment: read about **java.lang** package that is automatically imported in every java file.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? [The question it is a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14008664/2846923) has +33/-0, and is much less detailed...

Comment: The technical reason is answered in the duplicate question so we don't need another question to ask it again.  The "why" question is off-topic as that is not a concrete programming issue.  The Java designers could have decided to have everything in `java.util` added into `java.lang` but they decided against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The obvious answer is because `String` is used far more often than `HashMap`.

No. `String` belongs to `java.lang` package, which is automatically imported by the compiler.

From [`java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) javadoc:

> Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java programming language. The most important classes are `Object`, which is the root of the class hierarchy, and `Class`, instances of which represent classes at run time.

And from [Java Language Specification. Chapter 7. Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html)

> A package consists of a number of compilation units ([§7.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3)). A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the `public` types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.

Answer (score 3):

Those classes that you don't have to import are those classes in the `java.lang` package.

The [JLS, Chapter 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html), states:

> A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang.

`String`, `Integer`, `Character`, `Exception`, and `Boolean` are all in the `java.lang` package.  However, `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are in the `java.util` package and, as you already know, need to be imported (or they could be fully qualified) if used.