# Why in order to use some methods, their classes have to be imported?

Tags: java

For example, I never need to import Math class to use its method like Math.sqrt().

I have heard the word **hard-coded** used by some people to refer Math class being sorta "pre-program into each API.

I look the word up. The definition says it means something being fixed and can not be altered unless the whole program is modified. This is sounds more like **final** method to me.

Comment: Classes in `java.lang` are imported automatically. See [How does Java decide when to import?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008664/how-does-java-decide-when-to-import)

Comment: I also ask for people to clarify the word hard code for me

Comment: `hard-code` is not a technical term. We cannot clarify its meaning here. You should ask the people who use it what it means to them.

Comment: But what is it anyway? When something is hard coded

Comment: In my terminology hard-coded is when some variable is set to a value in the code and there is no way to change this value except by changing the code.

Comment: How can it be related to final, which as I was taught pretty much does the same thing to a method/constant ect.?

Answer (score 1):

Classes in `Java.Lang` are implicitly imported, and you don't have to import them yourself.

One (of many) simple definition of hard coded: When something is "hard coded" it is not a variable (of any type).

However, note that there are many definitions of hard coded and you should really refer to the person who mentioned it (Thank you Radiodef for reminding me)

For example, if i wrote a function

```
public int x() {
    return 2;
}
```

One could consider this function "hardcoded" to return a 2.

Comment: A instance variable, local variable... Which type

Comment: And how can it be related to final? (I think it can b/c I saw the definition google gave me/ stated in the question)

Comment: Wait isn't that the definition of a constructor?

Comment: No, the code snippet in my answer is a function that returns an int (in this case, the int 2). Hard coded is not a technical term and is in no way related to the keyword `final`. @Doeser

Comment: So for example, int something = varibleA.x, something = 2 right?

Comment: My function can be used as follows: `int y = someobject.x();` y will be equal to 2.

Comment: Yea, forgot to put the parameter

Answer (score 0):

The Java.Lang is automatically imported for us and we don't need to explicitely import it.

Often hard - coding may refer to using a litteral value instead of setting that value in a variable and then using the variable (however it may have a broader meaning)

Also considering the title of your question and the example you have given about Java.Lang.Math class, I would like to add this.

- First we don't really have to import a class in order to use it's method. We can also access the methods of a given class without importing and by using the fully qualified name of a class (provided that the library containing these classes is correctly referenced by our application; like when the classes are packed in a jar file for example).

**Basic syntax of the import statement is**:

```
import <pkg_name>[.<sub_pkg_name>]*.<class_name>;
```

OR

```
import <pkg_name>[.<sub_pkg_name>]*.*;
```

**Examples of the statement are**:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import shipping.gui.reportscreens.*;
```

**The import statement does the following**:

- Precedes all class declarations
- Tells the compiler where to find classes

Now for example, if I don't want to use an import statement to access the methods from the File class I can use a statement like

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:\\test.txt");
```

And that statement is perfectly valid with java