# Why don't you have to add an import statement for the java.lang.Runnable interface?

Tags: java

I am just learning Java and I wrote this little snippet and noticed that the compiler did not complain that I had no `import` statement for the `Runnable` interface. Why is that so?

```
package Practice.Java.Swing;

public class MainWindowEventLoop implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: `Runnable` is in the `java.lang` package, which gets implicity imported when compiling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008664/how-does-java-decide-when-to-import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there's a default, implicit import of `java.lang.*`. From [JLS§7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3):

> Every compilation unit implicitly imports every public type name declared in the predefined package `java.lang`, as if the declaration `import java.lang.*;` appeared at the beginning of each compilation unit immediately after any `package` statement. As a result, the names of all those types are available as simple names in every compilation unit.

Answer (score 3):

Any public class or interface present in the package java.lang can be used without importing it.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html):

> A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang.

For example you don't need to import `java.lang.String` for the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

Because all classes from java.lang are imported automatically.